# Ionic 2: hide an element in ion-item (or ion-card) of ion-list when other element in the same ion-item is clicked

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a list of photo objects in a photos object. These photos are shown in `ion-list`. And for each item I have a like, comment, and share buttons.

I built the share button with `ion-fab` so i can open two share buttons (share on facebook, twitter) when the share button in the `ion-card` is clicked.

What I want to do is hide the like and comment buttons when the share `ion-fab` opens.

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-card *ngFor="let photo of photos | async; let i = index;">
        <img [src]="photo.img"/>
        <span>{{photo.caption}}</span>
        <button ion-button>like</button>
        <button ion-button>comment</button>
        <ion-fab right>
            <button ion-fab (click)="shareFabClicked(photo, i)">
                <ion-icon name="share-alt"></ion-icon>
            </button>
            <ion-fab-list side="left">
                <button ion-fab (click)="share(photo, 'facebook')">
                    <ion-icon name="logo-facebook"></ion-icon>
                </button>
                <button ion-fab (click)="share(photo, 'twitter')">
                    <ion-icon name="logo-twitter"></ion-icon>
                </button>
            </ion-fab-list>
        </ion-fab>
    </ion-card>
</ion-list>
```

Assume that there is sass to style each element in the `ion-card`.

I need help on hiding the like and comment buttons when the share `ion-fab` opens. In general, how do you refer elements in an `ion-item` (or `ion-card`) of an `ion-list` and manipulate each element without affecting elements of other `ion-item`s

Note: One thing i can do (but chose not to do) is have flags in the photo object to hide and show each button. The reason I did not want to go with this approach is the photos object can be very big and I did not want to add more data to it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my question based on @Akash Nigam's solution. Thanks @Akash. I went further and came up with the solution below and avoided using arrays and adding extra flags to the photos object.

The solution involves two TypeScript variables, ngClass, and one sass class. And there is also a reference to the share ion-fab.

In the HTML code, `[ngClass]="{'hide' : hide && index==i}` is added in the like and comment tags. And `#shareFab` is added in the ion-fab tag.

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-card *ngFor="let photo of photos | async; let i = index;">
        <img [src]="photo.img"/>
        <span>{{photo.caption}}</span>

        <!-- apply the 'hide' class if hide = true and index = i -->
        <button ion-button [ngClass]="{'hide' : hide && index==i}>
            like
        </button>

        <button ion-button [ngClass]="{'hide' : hide && index==i}>
            comment
        </button>

        <ion-fab right #shareFab>
            <button ion-fab (click)="shareFabClicked(photo, i, shareFab)">
                <ion-icon name="share-alt"></ion-icon>
            </button>
            <ion-fab-list side="left">
                <button ion-fab (click)="share(photo, 'facebook')">
                    <ion-icon name="logo-facebook"></ion-icon>
                </button>
                <button ion-fab (click)="share(photo, 'twitter')">
                    <ion-icon name="logo-twitter"></ion-icon>
                </button>
            </ion-fab-list>
        </ion-fab>
    </ion-card>
</ion-list>
```

And in the sass code, the hide class is defined:

```
.hide {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

And finally, in the TypeScript code, in the share method, the hide and index variables are set to hide/show the like and comment buttons according to the state of the share fab button:

hide: Boolean;
index: Number;

shareFabClicked(p, i, shareFab: FabContainer) {
    console.log('share fab clicked');

```
if (shareFab._listsActive) {
  console.log('fab closing');
  this.hide = false;
} else {
  console.log('fab opening');
  this.hide = true;
}
this.index = i;

// TODO: share functionality
```

}

So basically, if index is equal to the index of the selected row and hide is true, the like and comment of the same row will be hidden; otherwise those two buttons are visible.

Answer (score 0):

You can have an array for hidden button photos which stores flags for only photos whose like and comment buttons have been hidden:

```
public hidden: boolean[] = [];
```

In your html:

```
<button ion-button *ngIf="!hidden[i]">like</button>
<button ion-button *ngIf="!hidden[i]">comment</button>
```

In shareFabClicked() function:

```
public shareFabClicked(photo: any, i: number): void {
    if (this.hidden[i]) {
        this.hidden.splice(i, 1); // Remove the flag if the buttons are already hidden, so that they get displayed again.
    } else {
        this.hidden[i] = true;
    }
}
```

So by using this way, you don't have to add data to the photos object. And more importantly your flag array won't ever get too big as you are only storing the flags for buttons which have to be hidden.

Comment: Thanks Akash. I also answered the question a little differently based on your answer. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome. I used array because I thought you might need 2 different photos to have their buttons hidden at the same time. But if that is not the case, then not using array is the best solution. :)